# AWK get first line

Tags: awk

I'm trying to add a column for each line together, and I do it like this:

```
awk '{s+=$2} END {print s}'
```

Now, when I have the final sum, s, I want to subtract the second column of the first line, like this:

```
awk '{s+=$2} {a= COLUMN 2 OF FIRST LINE } END {print s - a}'
```

How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just exclude the first line:

```
awk 'FNR>1{s+=$2};END{print s}'
```